# How can I delete an instance of a chart using chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

My web page loads and automatically creates a chart with data it pulls from an API I wrote.
Ive also got a HTML input that allows me to select the month. I have added an event listener to that input that triggers a function to draw a new chart based on the month i have selected (it recalls the api too with these new parameters).

It looked like it worked, but on further inspection, I realised that the previous chart was behind the new chart.

Is there a way i can remove the old chart?

```
<div class="chart_div" style="max-height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 5px">
  <label for="monthSelector">Start month:</label>

  <input
    type="month"
    id="monthSelector"
    name="start"
    min="{{min_date}}"
    max="{{today_date}}"
    value="{{today_date}}"
  />
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"> </canvas>
</div>

<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var monthSelector = document.getElementById("monthSelector");
  //  event listener for month slider
  monthSelector.addEventListener("input", function () {
    selected_date = monthSelector.value + "-01";
    drawChart(selected_date);
  });
  var today = monthSelector.value + "-01";

  //  Draw chart upon loading page
  drawChart(today);

  function drawChart(date) {
    x_labels = [];
    data_set_scratches = [];
    data_set_medical_scores = [];
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var url_scratches =
      "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-daily-scratch-count/" + date + "/";
    var url_medical_scores =
      "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-daily-medical-score/" + date + "/";

    // get x label based on dates of selected month
    var date_vals = date.split("-");
    var num_days = getDaysInMonth(date_vals[1], date_vals[0]);
    console.log(num_days);
    for (var i = 1; i <= num_days; i++) {
      var num = minTwoDigits(i);
      x_labels.push(num);
    }

    //  call api to fetch the data
    Promise.all([
      fetch(url_scratches)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(function (data) {
          var scratches = data;
          var dateIndex = 0;
          var scratchesIndex = 0;
          while (scratchesIndex < scratches.length) {
            var scratchDates = scratches[scratchesIndex].date.split("-"); //  Splits date into list ["YYYY", "MM", "DD"]
            //  if dates are equal, push total and increase both index
            if (scratchDates[2] == x_labels[dateIndex]) {
              data_set_scratches.push(scratches[scratchesIndex].total);
              dateIndex += 1;
              scratchesIndex += 1;
              //  if dates are not equal, push 0 and increase only date index
            } else {
              data_set_scratches.push(0);
              dateIndex += 1;
            }
          }
          console.log(data_set_scratches);
        }),
      fetch(url_medical_scores)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(function (data) {
          var medicalScores = data;
          var dateIndex = 0;
          var scoreIndex = 0;
          while (scoreIndex < medicalScores.length) {
            var scoreDates = medicalScores[scoreIndex].date.split("-"); //  Splits date into list ["YYYY", "MM", "DD"]
            // if dates are equal, push score then increase both index
            if (scoreDates[2] == x_labels[dateIndex]) {
              data_set_medical_scores.push(medicalScores[scoreIndex].score);
              dateIndex += 1;
              scoreIndex += 1;
              //  if dates are not equal, push 0 and increase only date index
            } else {
              data_set_medical_scores.push(0);
              dateIndex += 1;
            }
          }
          console.log(data_set_medical_scores);
        }),
    ]).then(function () {
      //  Creat chart from api Data
      let chartTest = new Chart(myChart, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
          labels: x_labels,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Scratch Total",
              fill: false,
              data: data_set_scratches,
              borderColor: "green",
              borderWidth: 1,
              lineTension: 0,
              backgroundColor: "red",
              pointBackgroundColor: "red",
              pointBorderColor: "red",
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: "red",
              pointHoverBorderColor: "red",
            },
            {
              data: data_set_medical_scores,
              label: "Medical Score",
              fill: false,
              borderColor: "orange",
              borderWidth: 1,
              lineTension: 0,
              backgroundColor: "#e755ba",
              pointBackgroundColor: "#55bae7",
              pointBorderColor: "#55bae7",
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#55bae7",
              pointHoverBorderColor: "#55bae7",
            },
          ],
        },
        options: {
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Daily Scratches/Medical Scores",
          },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [
              {
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                },
              },
            ],
            xAxis: [
              {
                ticks: {
                  stepSize: 1,
                  autoSkip: false,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      });
    });
  }

  // function to get num of days in month
  function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  }

  function minTwoDigits(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? "0" : "") + n;
  }
</script>
```

What I would really like to do is delete the existing chart before the api is called again? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

call the destroy method of the chart object

```
.destroy()
Use this to destroy any chart instances that are created. This will clean up any references stored to the chart object within Chart.js, along with any associated event listeners attached by Chart.js. This must be called before the canvas is reused for a new chart.

// Destroys a specific chart instance
myLineChart.destroy();
```

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html?h=destroy